# phonegap camera works on iPhone, but not iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, jquery-mobile, cordova, camera

I am new to PhoneGap, and I am building an app using PhoneGap + JQuery Mobile (cordova-1.7.0rc1).

trying to use the camera API and I run the app on the iPhone and everything works great.
trying to connect my iPad and test the app but I see this in the log:

> Error: executing module function 'setInfo' in module 'cordova/plugin/ios/device'. Have you included the iOS version of the cordova-1.7.0rc1.js file?

looked in PhoneGap site and they have only one JS for all iOS devices....
what am I missing?

thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Shaz:

You probably added the www project as a group, not a folder reference.
Add as a folder reference. Also, iOS 5 is a bit finicky, try a clean
first.

See this image:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/img/guide/getting-started/ios/create-folder-reference.png
From: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS

Comment: yeah, I had to rebuild the application according to the links provided and it all worked just fine :-)

Thanks a lot Shaz